# Incremental Subdomain Brute forcing?

Tags: nginx, subdomain, varnish, amazon-elb, brute-force-attacks

Currently looking after a small varnish/nginx webserver group sitting behind an AWS ELB.

Monitoring of the primary domain recently picked up a huge number of hits to non-existent sub-domain addresses.

On further inspection of the varnish logs it has revealed a handful of IP's running python agents attempting to incrementally brute force load sub-domains by without a word list.

Atm it has not moved beyond 4 characters ie. aaaa.primarydomain.com and up. It's presently at fau9.primarydomain.com

The speed and serving of 404's was creating a minor nuisance, so detection after a certain threshold and blocking was setup, as well as contacting abuse departments. So far about 10 IP's all of which are via btcentralplus.com, have come along and subsequently been blocked. It would seem to be coming from an amateur botnet and probes on the IP's have revealed what is consistent with home and small business networks in the UK.

More to the point though is the motive, I am dumbfounded as to the point of such an attack. For starters there is literally nothing to gain via this and even if there was obviously, attempting to brute-force a domain list incrementally seems beyond stupid? Not that that is an absolute deterrent.

The only suggestions we've come up with would be script-kiddy fails, an odd worm attempting god knows what or some kind of fake traffic generation? btcentralplus being the only common variable, seems to be next to useless for handling abuse complaints. If they were attempting to pump out their reverse DNS entry in webserver logs that might be exposed for instance? But even still, seems bizarre.

Comment: Can you add an example of some of the logs for these requests?

Comment: >19 ReqStart     c x.x.x.x
19 RxRequest    c GET
19 RxURL        c /
19 RxProtocol   c HTTP/1.1
19 RxHeader     c host: bbo7.primary.com
19 RxHeader     c Accept: */*
19 RxHeader     c Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
19 RxHeader     c User-Agent: python-requests/1.2.3 CPython/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-39-generic
19 RxHeader     c X-Forwarded-For: x.x.x.x
19 RxHeader     c X-Forwarded-Port: 80
19 RxHeader     c X-Forwarded-Proto: http
19 RxHeader     c Connection: keep-alive
19 VCL_call     c hash
19 Hash         c /

Comment: theres nothing unique in the requests. like i mentioned, it just hits / directly and cycles through subdomains incrementally. bbo7, bbo8 bbo9, bbpa, bbpb -- 9999 etc.

Answer (score 0):

They're doing some very simple information gathering. Looking for any interesting subdomains you might have that could be open to play with or that might give away information that would help target your main site.

For this reason it's generally a good idea to put internal or private sudomains behind a firewall or VPN so that they can't be accessed externally and/or put them on a separate TLD so that a casual scanner can't find them and associate them with your domain/company.

For example; Instead of using git.example.com you could use git.example.net or git.example-int.com. This is just basic security-by-obscurity as a first layer but it cuts back on simple scans like this one.

If it is a brand new or recently-scaled ELB it's possible they didn't mean to scan you at all and were targeting someone else but cached the DNS entry. You would have just happened to have inherited the IP they had cached.